# Force neural network to only product positive values

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

I have a custom neural network that has been written from scratch in python and also a dataset where negative target/response values are impossible, however my model sometimes produces negatives forecasts/fits which I'd like to completely avoid.

Rather than transform the input data or clip the final forecasts, **I'd like to force my neural network to only product positive values** (or values above a given threshold) during forward and back propagation.

I believe I understand what needs to be done during forward propagation - I need to set negative values to 0, however what I do not understand is how this **effects the back propagation** step and what I must do to ensure I propagate the "derivative of the clipping of negative values", if such a thing needs to happen or even makes sense.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, and I have added some example forward and back propagation code below **with the forward prop update I believe I need to make**.

**TLDR:** How do I ensure y_hat is always positive and correctly back propagate if any updates are made to forward propagation

FYI: I am using the **ReLU** activation function

##### Forward Prop code

```
z1 = x.dot(W1) + b1
a1 = activation(z1=z1)
y_hat = (a1.dot(W2) + b2).A1
# y_hat[y_hat<0] = 0 # is this fine? If so, does anything need to happen in backprop?
```

##### Back Prop code

```
dCost = np.matrix((y_hat - y) / N).T
dW2 = (a1.T).dot(dCost)
db2 = np.sum(dCost)
da1 = dCost.dot(W2.T)
dz1 = np.multiply(da1, d_activation(z1=z1))
dW1 = np.dot(x.T, dz1)
db1 = np.sum(dz1)
```

Comment: So what's wrong with ReLU?

Comment: If I am able to apply ReLU again to y_hat before returning, then I guess nothing - my issue is I am not sure how this changes back propagation e.g. do I need to apply the derivative of ReLu to dCost?

Comment: FYI, there are a number of activations functions you could use to contrain your values between 0 and 1 (sigmoid, ReLU, softplus, ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function), some being more easily derivable than others.

Answer (score 1):

The ReLU (or "clipping negative values") is defined as $f(x) = max(0, x)$ so it's derivative is
$$ 
f'(x) = 
     \begin{cases}
       0 &\quad\text{if}\qquad x < 0 \\
       \text{undefined} & \quad \text{if} \qquad x = 0 \\
       1 &\quad\text{if }\qquad x > 0\\
     \end{cases}
$$
To deal with the undefined case you usually assign $0$ or a very small fraction $e$. Using gradient chaining rule to calculate all the gradients you have to multiply `dCost` by $f'(x)$ which leaves you with the following code.

```
dCost = np.matrix((y_hat - y) / N).T
dy_hat = dCost.copy()
dy_hat[y_hat <= 0] = 0
dW2 = (a1.T).dot(dy_hat)
...
```

You can find more throrough explanation [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546020/neural-network-backpropagation-with-relu).

Comment: Awesome, that worked. Thank you very much Yuseq!

Comment: @Sharma you wrote “Rather than…clip the final forecasts” and that is precisely what this does. I can see some reasons why it might be okay to do it formally with an activation function, but it is worth pointing out that hitting the output with ReLU does just clip the output.

Comment: @Dave Correct, however with this method, I was also able to prevent/clip extremely large values from being produced during the fitting process, which also reduced the time taken to fit the model.